# Real Time Reporting API : Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: google-analytics-api, php-5.6, google-reporting-api

```
<?php if (is_null($_SESSION['auth']['id'] )) {
$where = "login='" . $_SESSION['auth']['login'] . "'";
 header('location: /khawla/index.php');
}

?>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-111358192-1"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-111358192-1');
</script>

</head>
<body> <?php 

$optParams = array(
'dimensions' => 'rt:medium');

try {

 $results = $analytics->data_realtime->get(
'ga:UA-111358192-1',
'rt:activeUsers',
$optParams);
  // Success. 
  } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
   // Handle API service exceptions.
  $error = $e->getMessage();
     } 

 function printRealtimeReport($results) {
  printReportInfo($results);
   printQueryInfo($results);
   printProfileInfo($results);
printColumnHeaders($results);
  printDataTable($results);
  printTotalsForAllResults($results);
  }

 function printDataTable(&$results) {
     if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {
    $table .= '<table>';

         // Print headers.
     $table .= '<tr>';

       foreach ($results->getColumnHeaders() as $header) {
      $table .= '<th>' . $header->name . '</th>';
   }
           $table .= '</tr>';

       // Print table rows.
     foreach ($results->getRows() as $row) {
     $table .= '<tr>';
   foreach ($row as $cell) {
    $table .= '<td>'
    . htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_NOQUOTES)
    . '</td>';
  }
  $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';

   } else {
   $table .= '<p>No Results Found.</p>';
  }
 print $table;
}
 function printColumnHeaders(&$results) {
 $html = '';
 $headers = $results->getColumnHeaders();

 foreach ($headers as $header) {
   $html .= <<<HTML
  <pre>
   Column Name       = {$header->getName()}
   Column Type       = {$header->getColumnType()}
   Column Data Type  = {$header->getDataType()}
   </pre>
    HTML;
 }
  print $html;
}
  function printQueryInfo(&$results) {
 $query = $results->getQuery();
 $html = <<<HTML
 <pre>
 Ids         = {$query->getIds()}
 Metrics     = {$query->getMetrics()}
 Dimensions  = {$query->getDimensions()}
 Sort        = {$query->getSort()}
Filters     = {$query->getFilters()}
 Max Results = {$query->getMax_results()}
  </pre>
 HTML;
 print $html; }
   function printProfileInfo(&$results) {
 $profileInfo = $results->getProfileInfo();
 $html = <<<HTML
 <pre>
    Account ID               = {$profileInfo->getAccountId()}
    Web Property ID          = {$profileInfo->getWebPropertyId()}
    Internal Web Property ID = {$profileInfo->getInternalWebPropertyId()}
    Profile ID               = {$profileInfo->getProfileId()}
    Profile Name             = {$profileInfo->getProfileName()}
   Table ID                 = {$profileInfo->getTableId()}
   </pre>
    HTML;
    print $html;
  } 
 function printReportInfo(&$results) {
    $html = <<<HTML
  <pre>
     Kind                  = {$results->getKind()}
  ID                    = {$results->getId()}
   Self Link             = {$results->getSelfLink()}
   Total Results         = {$results->getTotalResults()}
  </pre>
   HTML;
print $html;
}
         function printTotalsForAllResults(&$results) {
    $totals = $results->getTotalsForAllResults();
      foreach ($totals as $metricName => $metricTotal) {
        $html .= "Metric Name  = $metricName\n";
   $html .= "Metric Total = $metricTotal";
      }
       print $html;
}
```

i have this error when i use Real Time Reporting API even though i modified my id and i can't understand where is the problem
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwG4N.png)

Comment: Where are you instanciating the `analytics` object? check out the examples in the [embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started) to see how to create the analytics object. Check the account you are using. `console.log(EVERY_API_RESPONSE)`. It seems to me you are confusing tracking code (you are loading google tag manager) and reporting code.

Comment: how can I instanciate  the analytics object?

Comment: Check out the ["Copy and Paste Code" example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started#copy-and-paste). Or the [Java Script "Hello Analytics" example.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js)

Comment: but I have to use Realtime reporting api, it's an obligation !

Comment: how i use "google-api-php-client-master" with realtime reporting api please !!!!!

Comment: Use the hello analytics quick start guide for php web applications. Once you get Oauth working with the correct scope it is trivial to use any Google Analytics API.